# How can i use array of objects from database as filter?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, database

```js
// filter with data from database not working
app.filter('position', function($http, dbOperations) {
  console.log(dbOperations.getAccessPosition());
  var positions = []; //[{name:"cashier",id:1},{name:"operator",id:2}];
  // get the object array from database with name and id
  dbOperations.views("getPositions", "").then(function(res) {
    positions = res; // this is the desired value: [{name:"cashier",id:1},{name:"operator",id:2}]
  });
  var poitionName = "";
  return function(positionNum) {
    positions.forEach(function(p) {
      if (p.id == positionNum) {
        poitionName = p.name;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return poitionName;
  }
});

app.service('dbOperations', function($http) {
  this.getAccessPosition = function() {
    return $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/common/functions.php",
      data: {
        'process': "getAccessPosition",
        'data': ""
      }
    }).then(function success(res) {
      return res;
    }, function myError(response) {
      // console.log("Error");
    });
  }
});
```

When I console.log the positions, it prints the data that I need. but the filter is not working. maybe because the data is from database and it is waiting to respond. dbOperations is the in the service and I use $http.
Please help me with this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

In the service, just return the http request instead of unwrapping the promise.

```
app.service('dbOperations', function($http) {
  this.getAccessPosition = function() {
    return $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/common/functions.php",
      data: {
        'process': "getAccessPosition",
        'data': ""
      }
    })
  }
});
```

in the filter do the service call inside the callback function.

```
app.filter('position', function($http, dbOperations) {
  console.log(dbOperations.getAccessPosition());
  var positions = []; //[{name:"cashier",id:1},{name:"operator",id:2}];

  var poitionName = "";
  return function(positionNum) {
    dbOperations.views("getPositions", "").then(function(res) {
      positions = res.data;
      positions.forEach(function(p) {
       if (p.id == positionNum) {
        poitionName = p.name;
        return false;
       }
      });
      return poitionName;
    });    
  }
});
```